# What will be the size(memory)of NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, nsmutablearray

I am parsing json data,and i store them into an `NSMutableArray`.
For each data,parameters are as the following format,

```
{
    "id":"6",
    "username":"biju",
    "password":"biju123",
    "usertype":"2",
    "first_name":"biju",
    "last_name":null,
    "email":"b@b.com",
    "blocked":"N",
    "created":"2012-11-02 16:03:19",
    "image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.254\/eatthos\/assets\/upload\/users\/1351852399_thumb.jpg","thumb_image":"1351852399_thumb.jpg",
    "menu_image":"0",
    "thumb_menu_image":"0",
    "city":"njdfh",
    "favorite_food":"kafh",
    "favorite_restaurant":"kafdhj",
    "phone_number":"0",
    "description":"0",
    "token":"Dwx0DG",
    "fb_unique_id":null,
    "account_type":"normal",
    "twitter_id":null,
    "followers":"5",
    "follow":"N"
}
```

i am parsing about 100K of data,what will be the size(memory) of that array ?
Will it be a memory issue if i use it for an iphone app ?

Comment: This is also a useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515538/total-size-of-nsmutablearray-object?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array itself won't take that much space -- it's just a bunch of pointers. An array with tens of thousands of items can still only be a few dozen kilobytes. The space taken by the objects that the array contains is likely to be much more significant. But that is something only you can see -- there is no "size of an object in an array." It's like asking "How big is a ball?" It is possible that your data's space needs are problematic, and it's equally possible that there's no problem at all. As with many programming questions, I think the best answer is to try and see for yourself.

Comment: Thank u chuck...
i also belive it doesnt take so much of memory.
As u said to try n see by myself is not possible in my case...its a Social Networking App and user's info are saved in server page(lakhs of data will be stored only after the product is launched),i am parsing those data and showing on a UITableView(know it wont be a memory issue in case of Table,but i was bit confused about my array)

Answer (score 5):

You can try to find out size of your array with the following piece of code :

```
size_t total;
 id obj;
 for (obj in array)
 {
    total += class_getInstanceSize([obj class]);
 }

 NSLog(@"Array size : %ld",total); //This will return you size in bytes
```

you need to do : `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: This helped me stop a crash big-time, thank you. I was asynchronously downloading images from a webpages and when the images were too big, the app wouuld crash, by checking the image array size in each iteration of the web sniffer, I was able to stop the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Why can not you download 100 records each time like an apps then are in app store 
So, That the app will load quicker that before
If u want to see the flow of the memory you can go through this link http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/